# svg creating element all 3 seconds until i is x

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to figure out how i can create an svg Element all 3 seconds until i is == x.length.

I tried it in many many ways, but i cant find the Answer. Currently, this is my Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < whichBloons.length; i++) {

  setTimeout(function(i) {
    bloons[i].create(bloonCounter[i]);
  }, 10000, i);
```

}
}

I know I am doing something totally wrong, but i tried and googled now for Hours, but still having no clue.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` method delays the provided function with the specified amount of time in milliseconds. Instead of setting it to the constant duration of 10000 milliseconds you probably want so set it depending on your counter `i`. Every 3 seconds would be something like `(i+1) * 3000`

Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < whichBloons.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
    bloons[i].create(bloonCounter[i]);
  }, (i+1) * 3000, i);
}
```

Comment: In this case its still the same. It creates 14 Bloons after 3 seconds. But it should create one Bloon after 3 seconds until it created 14 bloons.

I hope you can follow me.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9bjc5np2/
I am using DIVs but it should be the same for SVG. Looks like the problem is somewhere else in your code...

Comment: I get it now. My 'whichBloons' Array has the size of 1. Thats because 'whichBloons' means the type of the bloons. Like this:

whichBloons = [0];
bloonCounter = [14];

So i want to create the type '0' 14 times all 3 seconds.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Just change the for-Loop to Loop 14 times. You could do something like `for (var i=0; i<14; i++)`

Comment: Somehow its still not working when i put '14' into the loop condition. All Elements are created the same time. 

I even dont know which code snippet could be the problem